Issue with SKAdNetwork IDs in Unity Ads Monetization
I am hoping to get some help around warning i see in Unity Ads dashboard “You have missing SKAdNetwork IDs from your Info.plist.”
screenshot of a warning in dashboard
I am not sure what is going on as I have updated my info.plist in swift xcode project and tried several builds (as well as via Testflight and normal version distribution which is available on App Store) but warning in the dashboard is not disappearing. I also confirmed via console logs that my info file SKAdNetworkItems are properly configured. So i am not sure what is going on and how to remove this warning. I am hoping to get community support to help me resolve this issue. Below is the raw file of my info.plist. Thank you all in advance!
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>22mmun2rn5.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>44jx6755aq.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>c6k4g5qg8m.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>3rd42ekr43.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>424m5254lk.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>7ug5zh24hu.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>9t245vhmpl.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>kbd757ywx3.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>3qy4746246.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>8s468mfl3y.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>v79kvwwj4g.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>w9q455wk68.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>294l99pt4k.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>4dzt52r2t5.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>glqzh8vgby.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>4w7y6s5ca2.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>97r2b46745.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>32z4fx6l9h.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>6yxyv74ff7.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>k674qkevps.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>av6w8kgt66.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>mlmmfzh3r3.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>5f5u5tfb26.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>wzmmz9fp6w.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>zmvfpc5aq8.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>3sh42y64q3.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>4pfyvq9l8r.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>f38h382jlk.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>488r3q3dtq.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>578prtvx9j.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>m8dbw4sv7c.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>f7s53z58qe.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>4468km3ulz.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>s39g8k73mm.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>n9x2a789qt.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>prcb7njmu6.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>ydx93a7ass.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>lr83yxwka7.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>5tjdwbrq8w.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>2u9pt9hc89.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>yclnxrl5pm.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>zq492l623r.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>4fzdc2evr5.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>v72qych5uu.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>mp6xlyr22a.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>a8cz6cu7e5.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>k6y4y55b64.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>5a6flpkh64.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>238da6jt44.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>5l3tpt7t6e.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>9rd848q2bz.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>ppxm28t8ap.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>t38b2kh725.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>tl55sbb4fm.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>x44k69ngh6.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>hs6bdukanm.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>wg4vff78zm.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>5lm9lj6jb7.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>f73kdq92p3.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>uw77j35x4d.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>9nlqeag3gk.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>a2p9lx4jpn.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>SKAdNetworkIdentifier</key>
            <string>mj797d8u6f.skadnetwork</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>


Xcode and Testflight builds; normal App Store version update. Switching between wifi and mobile connection. I would expect warning to disappear.

The image you posted shows the missing id.

But as you can see from my info.plist i posted above, my file has all necessary IDs.

That id is not in the list.

@hijinxbassist can you clarify please which ID exactly is not in the list? Thanks!


This notification in Unity Cloud is updated with a delay.
If you or any user with previous (older) build run the app, it triggers Unity Cloud, and this notification can be shown again.

